# PHPMailer and Gmail smtp, not getting sent or failed message

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Instead of using php's mail() function, I've been trying to set up PHPMailer with no success. I put in "echo here" for debugging purposes, and that is all it shows. I do not get any emails, or the sent or error messages. I'm stumped, and after researching it on here may switch to swift mailer. I'd really like to know what I screwed up though.

In my code, address is set to my email, and the username and password are set to a dummy account I made.

```
<?php
include('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$address = "test@gmail.com";
$body = "test email";

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'Web App');
$mail->Subject = "A Transactional Email From Web App";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($address, $name);
echo "Here";


if($mail->Send()) {
  echo "Message sent!";
} 
else {
      echo "Mailer Error: " ; $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Comment: you are sending mail in localhost or at server?

Comment: @aarju mishra i have it on my wesbite's file manager as mailer.php, so server

Comment: So what is the error showing

Comment: It doesn't show an error, It simply says Here.

Comment: Is two step authentication enabled on the account by chance?

Comment: @fyrye No, it says off.

Comment: I added this to the top of the script         ini_set('display_errors', 1);             and get Here
Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /class.phpmailer.php on line 1464   I might be able to figure it out!

Comment: It would help if you used a recent version, based your code on a current example, and read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Gmail I think you must make sure the gmail account has the insecure application auth activated